# Why can't I capture packet about Socks protocol by wireshark?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, wireshark

I surf the Internet through proxy by **shadowsocks**

Now I try to capture the packet about Socks protocol by wireshark(Vision 1.12.6) when I goto https://google.com

My packets is listing  here(I have sorted protocls by lexicographical order)[image]

I can't see any packets about Socks protocol.

Then I check my wireshark preferences, However I can't see Socks protocol.
[image]

Why and How can I capture packets about Socks protocol?

There is a normal situation that other people capture socks protocol packets. I want to work out the same as him.
[image]